# Cannot connect to my win 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, ping

When I ping a windows 7 machine from my win 8 tablet:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>ping alwyn-hp
>
> Pinging alwyn-hp.gateway.2wire.net [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
>   Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from 127.0.0.1:
>   bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms
>   TTL=128 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
>
> Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
>       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

When I try to address the computer via its IP directly

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC>ping
>   192.168.1.74
>
> Pinging 192.168.1.74 with 32 bytes of data: Request timed out. Request
>   timed out. Request timed out. Request timed out.
>
> Ping statistics for 192.168.1.74:
>       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

To begin with I'm extremely baffled how the DNS resolved to 127.0.0.1 which's normally reserved for localhost. I have already checked the host file and there's no irregular entry there.

I have also run the command, along with release/ renew

> ipconfig /flushdns

just to be sure.

Additionally I have rebooted both machines a couple of times and still no luck.

Of course shared directory, rdp, etc. is pretty much down - the machine is practically unreachable. That said the windows 7 machine seems perfectly capable of connecting out.

Before someone suggests firewall, it's down, same with AV they've been temporarily disabled.

Any thing else that I should look over?

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct name (maybe alwyn-hp is your win8 tablet)? Check IPconfig on both Win7 and Win8 and make sure you got the correct IP. If you ping a non-existent IP address, it will return timeout.

Comment: Check what `nslookup *win7machinename*` will show. Is your tablet reachable from windows 7 machine?

Comment: @Darius Pretty darn sure. My tablet is a Sony Vaio. Its name is Alwyn_Vaio. Also checked the IPConfig on both machines.

Comment: @ko4evneg I'll run that when I get a chance and may be post the result here.

Comment: Since you mentioned Win8 tablet... I'm guessing the tablet is connected to your home network using Wireless, and your Win7 is a PC connected using wired LAN? If yes, MAYBE there is "network isolation" feature on your Wireless? So from the Wireless side, you can't go into the LAN side, but the LAN side is free to connect to your wireless side.